# Cloning and removing the current table

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to remove the table which was cloned but removing only works for the first table not the current one.

I used these two codes but no luck.

```
$(this).closest('table').remove();
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

My intent is to make REMOVE span hidden at the beginning and make it visible for only cloned tables so that user cannot remove the first table and have something to be cloned. If you can help me achieving it as well then I'll be happier.

So far this is what I've done with my very little jquery knowledge: http://jsfiddle.net/sZwvd/1/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`event-delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) on dynamically created elements,

```
$('div').on('click','.remove-table', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();  
   $(this).closest('table').remove();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sZwvd/5/)

Comment: Didn't work. It only removes original table not the cloned ones.

Comment: Perfect it works now. For the second part of my question, shall I open another post so that you get more points, or would you be interested in solving it here?

Comment: @MadMax Yeah do open a new question, so that future readers will get benefits from them, and also your question get more attention from other experts on the site too.. By the way glad to help..!

Comment: New question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351107/adding-a-table-cell-into-only-cloned-table)