# Adding a table cell into only cloned table

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add a new **TD** into cloned table so it will only exist in cloned table not in original one. The reason is, I don't want users to remove original table otherwise there won't be anything to be cloned :)

**Currently like this:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="sizes">size</div>
            <div class="sizes">length</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**After cloning it should be like this:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="sizes">size</div>
            <div class="sizes">length</div>
        </td>
        <td class="remove-table"><span>REMOVE</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.add-another-table').click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var clonedTable = $(this).prev('table').clone();
      $(this).before(clonedTable);
   });
   $('div').on('click', '.remove-table', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).closest('table').remove();
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b3JdB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `.append()` that required element over that `clone`,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.add-another-table').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var clonedTable = $(this).prev('table').clone();
        $(this).before(clonedTable.find('.remove-table').remove().end().find('tr').append('<td class="remove-table"><span>REMOVE</span></td>').end());
    });

    $('div').on('click', '.remove-table', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('table').remove();
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/b3JdB/3/)

Comment: When I clone more than one time, Remove cells are been replicated so every new table has more than 1 remove cell.

Comment: Is there a way of extracting last td from table which is to be cloned? If there is then I can run `if lastTD != '<td class="remove-table"><span>REMOVE</span></td>' THEN add td ELSE don't add`